# Lightning:RecordEditForm - Set values to null after form submission

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, community, lightning-design-system

I have a Lightning:RecordEditForm that creates a record after the form has been submitted. Once the form has been saved, I require the values on the form to be set back to null, as multiple responses are reuqired without the page refreshing.

I have currently tried giving the lightning:inputField an aura id the setting that value to null within the onSuccess method but the value remains.

I have also tried setting the value to "" & NULL however neither have worked.

Component:

```
<lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="incidentForm" onsubmit="{!c.onRecordSubmit}" onsuccess="{!c.afterSubmit}" onload="{!c.onLoad}" objectApiName="Case" recordTypeId="0120c000001FwVPAA0">

    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Subject" aura:id="input_Subject" />

    <div class="slds-m-top_medium">
        <lightning:button disabled="{!v.disabled}" variant="brand" type="submit" name="save" label="Add" />
    </div>
</lightning:recordEditForm>
```

controller:

```
//Submit Incident
onRecordSubmit: function(component, event, helper) {        
    event.preventDefault(); // stop form submission

    var eventFields = event.getParam("fields");
    component.find('incidentForm').submit(eventFields);
    helper.fireRefreshEvt(component); 
},

//On Success - After Incident Added 
afterSubmit : function (component, event, helper) {
    component.find("input_Subject").set("v.value", "");      
    helper.getIncidents(component);
},
```

Helper:

```
fireRefreshEvt : function(component) {
    var refreshEvent = $A.get("e.force:refreshView");
    if(refreshEvent){
        refreshEvent.fire();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the recordId argument of lightning:recordEditForm and assigning its value from an attribute which is an empty string?

Comment: No I havent tried that. Could you provide an example please?